# iOS enabling custom logger in release mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, logging, release

In a recent application, i have been asked to enable debug logging when releasing builds so the testers can send us the log when testing the application.
I have created a custom logger which depends on #IF DEBUG macro to enable or disable custom logging.
This works fine on debug mode. But when i build a new release (with Bamboo) the testers could not see the custom log anymore.
How can i enable my custom logging in release mode (via gcc_preprocessor_macros)? Should i rely on other preprocessor macros and ignore the DEBUG directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in release mode, `RELEASE` is defined. If you are in debug mode, `DEBUG` is defined. If you want your custom logging available in release mode, you shouldn't use `DEBUG` as your condition.

If your goal is not to send a release build to your testers, but to send a "looks like release" build to testers, I suggest duplicating the release configuration and defining a `PRETEND_RELEASE` in it. See `Your Project -> Info tab -> Configurations`.

Comment: But i am actually asked to send a build release (RCs are generated via Bamboo).Is there any other way that allows me to do that without adding a new configuration. Because i do not want to mess with the project.Is there a clean way to do it by using gcc_preprocessor_macros or some other configuration ?

Comment: When you ship your final build, do you want it to also be logging things? If you don't, you're going to need to differentiate your builds somehow -- a configuration is the most straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Your answer is right. However i have been told to manage some blabla .sh file in order to make this happen.